# Maven, How to Package ONLY Changed Files?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-release-plugin

I have a project of PL/SQL files (stored procedures). I need to hand an archive of only files that have changed to the DBA to execute for deployment to production. How can I create an archive with Maven that only contains files from the project that have changed since the last release?

Thanks

Comment: Changed since when? A previous commit?

Comment: Yes, since the previous release. Sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: How would calculate that ?

Comment: Why would you like to do that? Maybe you mean how to manage deltas in the database using maven?

Comment: Why would I like to do that: " I need to hand an archive of only files that have changed to the DBA to execute for deployment to production." Because the DB admin only needs to install to production the files that have changed for the current release and not everything.

I do not need to make any kind of comparison to what is in the database. I only need to know from the SCM which files have changed, and package those into an archive.

Answer (score 0):

In case of database scripts, look for solutions like liquibase or solidbase. These frameworks are capable of recognizing which scripts have already been executed and where to start from.